# Qt, catch form values in QNetworkRequest

Tags: c++, qt, http, webforms, request

I have a **QWebView** component in my Qt widget application. And I have already created a network manager to handle requests from the **QWebView**.

What I want to do is catching the values of the web form inside **QWebView**, up to this point of time I have the **QNetworkRequest** instance of every network request.

**How to extract the form values from the QNetworkRequest instance**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function of `QNetworkRequest` class:

```
QByteArray QNetworkRequest::rawHeader ( const QByteArray & headerName ) const
```

which returns the raw form of header named `headerName`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the values on the get method?

```
    int i= 0;
    QPair<QString , QString > values;
    while( i < ui->webView->url().queryItems().count() )
    {
        values =  ui->webView->url().queryItems().at( i );
        i++;
    }
```